# Messages getting stuck in ActiveMQ queue

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, queue, activemq-classic

Our enterprise search based application which is on JDK 1.6.43, MySQL 5.1, Apache Tomcat 6.0.33, ActiveMQ 5.2.0 & Apache Solr 4.3.1 has an issue with messages(solr docs) being stuck in queue. Only server restart flushes those message.

Detailed description:
Java(Struts) based application logs every action & makes few of them as a message(solr doc) & push them through a queue into solr DB & upon only any exception logs into a file.
Over weekend, when the load is less, this queue gets stuck. Upon server restart, these messages goes into solr DB. So basically, there is no data of weekend to be seen until a server is restarted neither there is any log to trace (as there is no exception).

Need urgent resolution & help on this as its a production scenario & giving a hard time with customer data analysis.

Comment: As there is no configuration or property file for setting the queue attributes, had to enable JMX configuration in tomcat & could see those properties via jconsole.

Comment: In general, I would suggest that you upgrade your ActiveMQ broker - 5.2 is around 5 years old at this stage, and hundreds of issues have been resolved since. It may very well be that this is one of them. If this is still happening, then you should post up your broker configuration with details of what JMS/ActiveMQ features you are using and any additional statistics from JMX that you think might help.

Comment: Thanks Jake for the reply.

We will for sure think about updating the ActiveMQ to the latest or at-least ver 5.5.

As of now, we are using embedded broker with default settings only & instantiating like below,

ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");

Comment: I'm using 5.8 and having same problem. See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ENTMQ-444